# How to add contact from two different Telegram servers?

Tags: c#, telegram

Adding a contact from a country like Iran to a telegram account from Canada, causes an error says:

> Unfortunately -name- has not joined telegram yet. But you can send
>   them an invitation.

I think that's because there are two different accounts from two different servers that aren't synced well.

Sometimes Iranian account can add Canadian account, and then Canadian can add Iranian as well, even if Iranian deletes Canadian from contacts. Or if a third person share their contacts or forward a message from one to another, they can add each other. I think these signs shows that telegram servers are not synced well.

As I'm using [TLsharp](https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp) to accomplish that, I can add two telegram accounts, one plays as that third person role, and shares Iranian contact to Canadian, and then he can save that contact.
My step by step plan is:

1. What I have is an Iranian Telegram account and Canadian one.
2. Iranian Customer opens my web site.
3. she/he fills telegram phone number field and submits.
4. we are going to start sending message in telegram by Canadian account.
5. try to add contact by Canadian account.
6. If failed, try to add contact by Iranian account. Else, we are done!
7. Share contact to Canadian Account.
8. Add contact by Canadian account.

My problem is:

1. how to have multiple telegram accounts in my code, because session file name is always "session.dat"
2. how to share contact in TLSharp

I can't forward message because there isn't any message yet. We should start messaging.

I also tried retrieving `UserId` and `AccessHash` by Iranian account, and using by Canadian account in this method:

```
await client.SendMessageAsync(new TLInputPeerUser() { UserId = xxx, AccessHash= yyyy}, "Hello");
```

but it has `PEER_ID_INVALID` error. (That is not true, I just took `UserId` from telegram!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in number of contacts!
Telegram only supports about 1000 contacts (I found it experimental, there isn't any official source to prove this), and it will show you error when you want to add more contacts. 
Trying to delete some contacts and reduce the count to 900, allowed me to add new contacts. So, the problem is not in telegram servers, it is in number of contacts limitation. Maybe they have a line of code like this:

```
Contact[] contacts = new Contact[1000]; //LOL
```

And for other two questions:

> 1. how to have multiple telegram accounts in my code, because session
>      file name is always "session.dat"

```
TLSharp.Core.TelegramClient clientAlt = new TLSharp.Core.TelegramClient(api_id, api_hash, sessionUserId: "sessionAlt");
```

There isn't any good documentation for [TLSharp](https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp), but the problem solved by using `sessionUserId` as an optional parameter.

> 2. how to share contact in TLSharp?

```
TLInputMediaContact contact = new TLInputMediaContact()
{
    FirstName = FirstName,
    LastName = LastName,
    PhoneNumber = PhoneNumber 
};
TLRequestSendMedia req = new TLRequestSendMedia()
{
    Media = contact,
    Peer = new TLInputPeerUser() { UserId = AnotherTelegramAccountUserID.Id },
    RandomId = UniqueNumber_ToPreventDuplicateMessages,
};
await clientAlt.SendRequestAsync<TLUpdates>(req);
```